# iPhone SDK: NSInvalidArgumentException -UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView

Tags: iphone

I am trying to develop a simple search mechanism on a UIPicker. The approach I am using is to keep two arrays. My problem is that for some reason I am getting this run-time error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]
```

Here are the array declarations.

```
//data source for UIPicker NSArray
*arrayCountryChoices;

//search results buffer 
NSMutableArray *arraySearchResults; 

//properties
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray*arrayCountryChoices; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *arraySearchResults;
```

Here is where I initialize the data

```
//create data
  arrayCountryChoices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];

//copy the original array to searchable array
arraySearchResults = [arrayCountryChoices mutableCopy];
```

An the picker methods.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [arraySearchResults count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [arraySearchResults objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
//grab the selected country
strUserChoice = [arraySearchResults objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Here is  the search code for completeness although not really relevant yet as the app dies before we ever get here.

```
//filter on search term
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", strSearchText];
[arraySearchResults filterUsingPredicate: predicate];
[pickerCountry reloadComponent:0];
```

I have also dragged datasource  and delegate connections from the UIPicker to  Files Owner in Interface Builder.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got the picker's data source set to something other than the object that implements the code you've posted there—apparently a UIView somewhere. Make sure the picker's outlets point to your actual data-source object.

Comment: It does seem like that but I have checked within IB that the picker  datasource  and delegate are set to Files Owner. Mmmm....

Comment: Also, the code posted above is from the CountryViewController. Within this objects, viewdidload method I put

 pickerCountry.dataSource = self;
 pickerCountry.delegate = self;

This still results in a run-time error that I do not understand. Any ideas?????

Comment: I'm not doing anything different that usual in terms of then NIB. In fact, I don't see any explicit code of this type other than this.

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
  self.title = @"Countries";
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: I think I have located part of the problem. If I comment out these lines.  //create data
 //arrayCountryChoices = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil]; 
 
 //copy the original array to searchable array
 //arraySearchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayCountryChoices];

Then, and empty picker loads. With the lines of code I  get a run-time error. Mmmmm?????

Comment: It looks like the problem might be with the searchArray. I thought at first it  was not being allocated. So, I added this line

arraySearchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc arrayWithArray:arrayCountryChoices];

This did not work. However, if I change all the Picker methods  within the view controller to  use the arrayCountryChoices, there  is no run-time error. For that reason, I suspect the searchArray does not have any data in it despite this call.

arraySearchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc arrayWithArray:arrayCountryChoices];


Can anyone comment on that possibility?